# pyPDF IOError Exception in OSX

Tags: python, pypdf

I am trying to open a pdf (named kalimera.pdf) using PdfFileReader from the pyPdf module, using the following set of commands

```
from pyPdf import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter
document = PdfFileReader(open('kalimera.pdf', 'rb'))
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pyPdf/pdf.py", line 374, in __init__
    self.read(stream)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pyPdf/pdf.py", line 702, in read
    stream.seek(-1, 2)
IOError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

The platform is OSX 10.11.3 and the python version is 2.7.10 (although this was reproduced in python3.5 as well).

Comment: Have you tried multiple PDF files for your input? I've tried an example PDF in Python 2.7.4 and I don't seem to get that `IOError`...

Comment: What do you mean multiple PDFs?
It doesn't work with any of the pdfs that I have in the working directory.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you are getting that error , you are reading the PDF file in binary mode and passing it to the PdfFileReader, maybe you should try with other PDF files.

Anyway, try to use : https://pythonhosted.org/PyPDF2/ its the latest version of PyPDF, and i think it supports python2.7.